# wsdl to java in eclipse

Tags: java, web-services

I am new to the web services and using Eclipse indigo to do the operation, I have one wsdl file by which i have created the client(java) files, Now i am using those files for my java files which is getting stub object from xxxxxbindingstub.java file and sending the request(setRequest.java) in order to get the response from the web service.

But I am getting the below error:-
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/axis/client/Stub
:(:(

Please help me out by suggesting something.

Thanks 
@rs

Comment: Please check your classpath for the appropriate libraries, add them if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing client application, I would suggest you to use `wsimport -keep http://url.com` instead of `wsdl2java`. It will generate stub classes. This util is in `bin` folder of your JDK package. If you still want to use Axis, check appropriate jar files in your classpath

Comment: Thanks Umar, but the application is in different system which doesn't allow to connect to the server, every time i have to develop the application, pack it and run over the server. I dont have permissions to access the server as it requires the VPN.

Comment: Not sure, that I understand your problem, you still can generate stub-classes using wsimport from local wsdl.

Answer (score 0):

Axis jar file is not included in the build path. You can download it from [Find Jar](http://findjar.com/index.x?query=org/apache/axis/client/Stub)

Comment: I have added the jar file axis.jar downloaded from "http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadaxisjar.htm" in the classpath.